# How to call the function only once, when i make a login/open app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have got a function and need only once call it, when the suer make login.

```
 function Read(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
    const starCountRef = ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId);
    
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        setCounter(data.countTrains);   
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      Read();
      console.log('counter:', counter)
  },[]);
```

I need to write data here into counter variable

Comment: use a flag and change the value of it if function has executed ... make the function inside if statement

Comment: This is not how to properly write a react component. You are defining a React component with state and all but then you are using an useEffect() outside your component. I'd recommend some tutorial on react development, maybe it will answer your questions way faster.

Comment: NOT your answer for reactjs but for those looking for native JavaScript there is an options `once` flag for an event listener you can utilize for that scenario that removes the event listener after it is called once. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, here is your function

```
const functionThatIsCalledOnlyOnce = ( counterValue ) => {
   setCounter(counterValue)
}
```

When you want to call this function? if you want to call it only once, when app open put it in useEffect:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
   functionThatIsCalledOnlyOnce(1);
  },[]);
```